# PyMongo group by multiple keys

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

With PyMongo, group by one key seems to be ok:

```
results = collection.group(key={"scan_status":0}, condition={'date': {'$gte': startdate}}, initial={"count": 0}, reduce=reducer)
```

results:

```
{u'count': 215339.0, u'scan_status': u'PENDING'} {u'count': 617263.0, u'scan_status': u'DONE'}
```

but when I try to do group by multiple keys I get an exception:

```
results = collection.group(key={"scan_status":0,"date":0}, condition={'date': {'$gte': startdate}}, initial={"count": 0}, reduce=reducer)
```

How can I do group by multiple fields correctly?

Comment: What is the function here in "reducer"? The `.group()` operator uses JavaScript code for these methods. You really should be using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead, for most cases unless you really need to use `.mapReduce()`. But I would prefer either option to `.group()`. Can you edit to include your "reduce" function and logic please?

Comment: reducer = Code("""
                function(obj, prev){
                prev.count++;
                }
                """)

Comment: I tried also: results = collection.group(["scan_status","date"], condition={'date': {'$gte': startdate}}, initial={"count": 0}, reduce=reducer)
without success

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to count over two keys then while it is possible using `.group()` your better option is via [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

This uses "native code operators" and not the JavaScript interpreted code as required by `.group()` to do the same basic "grouping" action as you are trying to achieve.

Particularly here is the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline operator:

```
result = collection.aggregate([
    # Matchn the documents possible
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": startdate } } },

    # Group the documents and "count" via $sum on the values
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "scan_status": "$scan_status",
            "date": "$date"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

In fact you probably want something that reduces the "date" into a distinct period. As in:

```
result = collection.aggregate([
    # Matchn the documents possible
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": startdate } } },

    # Group the documents and "count" via $sum on the values
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "scan_status": "$scan_status",
            "date": {
                "year": { "$year": "$date" },
                "month": { "$month" "$date" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Using the [**Date Aggregation Operators**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) as shown here.

Or perhaps with basic "date math":

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

result = collection.aggregate([
    # Matchn the documents possible
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": startdate } } },

    # Group the documents and "count" via $sum on the values
    # use "epoch" "1970-01-01" as a base to convert to integer
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "scan_status": "$scan_status",
            "date": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$date", date.fromtimestamp(0) ] },
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$subtract": [ "$date", date.fromtimestamp(0) ] },
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Which will return integer values from "epoch" time instead of a compisite value object.

But all of these options are better than `.group()` as they use native coded routines and perform their actions much faster than the JavaScript code you need to supply otherwise.