# incorrect result with showing the number of occurrence for a specific field in mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want each first_name with the count of its occurrence displayed how can I do that
this is the code i have tried on

```
v=school.aggregate(
    [ {'$group' : { '_id': '$first_name', 'count' : {'$sum' : 1}}} ]
    )
    
for x in v:

    pprint(x)
```

but the result is not correct
it shows me this

```
{'_id': None, 'count': 955180}
```

Comment: You want to find how many times does the first name appear?

Comment: yes for each different first name

Comment: Is first name is a list of names or is it a string?

Comment: not a list just a string

Answer (score 0):

You can just find all the IDs that contains the first name and then get the size of the list:

FirstNameCount = len(list(school.aggregate.find({"_id": first_name})))

Comment: i dont want to show the size, i want to show each first_name with its count

Comment: In that case I suggest you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31101326/6205564